# REACT.JS Passing a State through Components

Tags: reactjs, components, state

[image: Here is the situation I have)]

I should update a state in the component 'TimeDisplay' from the component 'TaskItem' (you can see the components hierarchy as it follows. How can I implement it?

Comment: docs - 'lifting state up' and pass value down as prop, use context api for more complex case

Comment: so the state should be declare in the top component which would be `Panel` in your example. You should use props to propage the state value to `TimeDisplay` and pass a `handler` to `TaskItem` to be able to trigger the state change. If it's a common scenario in your app, should should consider using redux

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into using Redux for global state management. It's got a bit of a learning curve but it is 100% worth it for this exact usage. The other way is have your state be at the top most component (Panel) and you can pass down whatever state your need to down as props to all the child components.

[Redux.js](https://redux.js.org/)